# Change the hide button for gnome-panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

Is there a way to change the hide button on the gnome-panel? What I mean is the buttons placed at the end of each side of the panel? I'm wondering if its possible, and if it is, how to go about doing it.

Panel hidden, button showing

[image: hidden]

Panel not hidden, buttons on each side

[image: not hidden]

Comment: are you referring to the look of the buttons or removing the buttons altogether?

Comment: The look of the buttons.

Comment: You should be able to change the look of the buttons through a icon theme - http://art.gnome.org/themes/icon/

Comment: @James Gifford -- Make that an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @djeikyb Done. :)

Answer (score 2):

How to change the look of the buttons through an icon theme:

1. Head to [Gnome-Art](http://art.gnome.org/themes/icon/) or [Gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org) and find yourself an icon theme you like.
2. To install the icon theme, head to Appearance settings and hit the "Install" button.

[image: Appearance settings]

3. Select the `.tar.bz2` file in the "Open File" dialog to install it.
4. Now, select the theme you're using as your base (I'm using the Ambient theme here), select "Customize", and then select the "Icons" tab - choose the icon set that you installed earlier, and you're done!

*Please note that you might have to logout and log back in for the icons to fully take effect - that's what I had to do*